# Is it possible to add comments to Firebase Firestore rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've been unable to find anything in the docs that say whether you can add comments, i.e.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      // Testing the removal of this line:
      // allow read: if true;
      allow read: if false;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any info online about the rules syntax? What language is it written in?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The language is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language).  It's called CEL ([common expression language](https://github.com/google/cel-spec)).  It's pretty clear from what you see that lines containing `//` are considered like C++ and Java to be comments from the point of `//` to the end of the line.

Comment: The comments get very verbose and there is no support for collapsing comments. I have gone through the Visual Studio market place but there is nothing there. Any idea as to whats the best way to manage comments in firestore.rules